# В текст в TextView по умолчанию идет выравнивание текста по левому краю. Как выровнять текст по всей ширине?

Tags: java, android

В текст в `TextView` по умолчанию идет выравнивание текста по левому краю. Как выровнять текст по всей ширине, как если бы в *Word* вы нажали `Ctrl+J`( текст распределяется равномерно между левым и правым краями страницы)???

Answer (score 6):

Андроид не умеет выравнивать текст в `TextView` по обеим сторонам. Используют или [`WebView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4314724), или сторонние библиотеки типа [TextJustify-Android](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android/wiki/3-%C2%B7-Examples).

Answer (score 5):

Должно помочь проставление `gravity` для `TextView` на `center`

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

За расположение содержимого внутри своего контейнера отвечает параметр `gravity`. Для того, чтобы содержимое размещалось по середине контейнера необходимо указать `layout:gravity="center"`. Однако это сработает если элемент занимает всю ширину своего родительского контейнера, т.е. если установлен параметр `android:layout_width="match_parent"`. Если длина установлена `wrap_content`, то тут надо устанавливать параметры расположения элементов в зависимости от конкретного `ViewGroup`. Например для `RelativeLayout` надо установить у элементов внутри него параметр `android:layout_centerInVertical="true"`.

Comment: Вопрос в другом, выравнивать надо по ширине, а не по центру

Answer (score 0):

Среди атрибутов вашего `Edit Text` можно найти  `textAlignment`, у которого в выпадающем списке выбрать нужное, или использовать строку:

```
android:textAlignment="center"
```

[image]